# General Question about User Identification in App Developement

Tags: flutter

I am new to Mobile App Developing and started out with Flutter. I have a fundamental Question about App Developing.

Basically I`ve tried to look into the mechanics of user identification and indepentant of that purchase management (buying, restoring, etc). I have skimmed through the example and description of the package in_app_purchase and didnt see anything to really identify the user by their AppStore/GooglePlay Account. So i guess the package just calls some System Method which asks AppStore/GooglePlay with the logged in (into the Device) User and the App from which the call comes from as context to fetch the purchases made by the user within the App. I think the reason for that could be to evade Devs from aquiring identifiying information without the users consent (so user data protection).

Did I get that right? Is there really no way to aquire some unique UserId from the AppStore/GooglePlay? If no, i guess the only way to get this information is by making the user create an account in your app, like in Web Development.